# Найти на странице родителя по тексту вложенного элемента

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

В коде страницы, которую я пытаюсь запарсить, есть следующий html-код:

```
<tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;">
        <span class="flagicon">
            <a href="//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_South_Korea.svg?uselang=ru" class="image" title="Республика Корея">
                <img alt="Республика Корея" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Flag_of_South_Korea.svg/22px-Flag_of_South_Korea.svg.png" width="22" height="15" class="thumbborder" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Flag_of_South_Korea.svg/33px-Flag_of_South_Korea.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Flag_of_South_Korea.svg/44px-Flag_of_South_Korea.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="900" data-file-height="600">
            </a>
        </span>
        <a href="/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F" class="mw-redirect" title="Южная Корея">Южная Корея</a>
    </th>
    <td style="background-color:#ff9090; color:black; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Необходимо заранее оформлять в консульстве визу. Безвизовый въезд возможен на 30 дней для транзита в США, Канаду, Австралию, Новую Зеландию и Японию  и при наличии виз этих стран. 30 дней (если уже были в Южной Корее не менее 4 раз за последние 2 года, или всего не менее 10 раз)
        <sup id="cite_ref-archive.travel.ru_66-0" class="reference">
            <a href="#cite_note-archive.travel.ru-66">[66]</a>
        </sup>. Возможно получить безвизово 30 дней, но только для посещения 
        <a href="/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE" title="Чеджудо">острова Чеджудо</a>
        <sup id="cite_ref-archive.travel.ru_66-1" class="reference">
            <a href="#cite_note-archive.travel.ru-66">[66]</a>
        </sup>
    </td>
    <td>Не менее 6 месяцев на момент подачи паспорта в консульство</td>
    <td>1 чистая страница</td>
    <td style="background-color:#ff9090; color:black; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Так же</td>
    <td style="background-color:#90ff90; color:black; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">90 дней</td>
</tr>
```

**Дано:** название страны. В данном случае, *Южная Корея*.

**Задача:** получить вышеуказанный html-код имея в распоряжении только название страны.

Что я для этого сделал:

```
def parseWiki(url):
    wantedCountryName = destinationCountry['name_translations']['ru']
    r = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    neededElement = soup.find('a', text=wantedCountryName)
    wantedTableRow = None
    for parent in neededElement.parents:
        if parent.name == 'tr':
            wantedTableRow = parent
    print(wantedTableRow)
```

Но почему-то получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parents'

В строке `for parent in neededElement.parents:`. Либо `soup.find('a', text=wantedCountryName)` почему-то не находит тег `a` с текстом `Южная Корея`, либо я неправильно задал условие поиска. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки в указанном коде нет. Я по ошибке подставлял неправильную ссылку(на англоязычную Википедию).